# Why does cross_val_score return several scores?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have the following code

```
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=0)
trainPrediction=tree.predict(trainData)
score=cross_val_score(tree, trainData, trainPrediction)
```

With the code above, I get a score that looks like this:

```
[0.96052632 0.93421053 0.89473684 0.94736842 0.92      ]
```

I was expecting just a single number as the score, and not an array. How do I read this code, which one would be considered the score?

Some other classifiers I tried (like SVM), have the `score(...)` function, which worked well. Decisiontree classifier also seems to have this function, but I get an error when I try to use it like:

```
trainScore=score(trainData, trainPrediction)
```

The error I get is: `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable`

Documentation shows this `score(X, y[, sample_weight])` But I don't really understand this I guess

The reason why I used `cross_val_score(...)` is cus they use it in the documentation of DecisionTree:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

Note

I also tried using: accuracy_score(...) like in this example:

[Accuracy score of a Decision Tree Classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204948/accuracy-score-of-a-decision-tree-classifier)

But this does not work, as this function is not part of this classifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) gives you the score evaluated by cross validation, which means that it uses K-fold cross validation to fit and predict using the input data. The result is hence an array of `k` scores, resulting from each of the folds. You have an array of `5` values because `cv` defaults to that value, but you can modify it to others.

Here's an example using the iris dataset:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=0)
cls = tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = cls.predict(X_test)
```

Now with the default settings:

```
score = cross_val_score(cls, X_test, y_test)
score
# array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Or for three folds:

```
score = cross_val_score(cls, X_test, y_test, cv=3)
score
# array([1., 1., 1.])
```

Also note that `cross_val_score` expects `X` and the target variable to try to predict, *not the predicted value*. Hence you should be feeding it `X_test` and `y_test`.

Comment: So with a cv=3 for instance, we divided the data into 3 parts, and use 2 parts for training, and the final part for testing right? But what would the 3 values in array with accuracy score correspond to? Does it mean that we just test accuracy on each of this divided data seperately, and get these 3 scores for each part of the divided data?

Comment: That's right yes. In each fold, we leave a small portion of the data to predict on. After the 3 folds, we have 3 scores, one from each @user1960836